# UITableViewCell additional information

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, properties

I got a hard job to be done. I try to attach additional information to a UITableViewCell.
The tableViewCells got buttons inside that I subclassed to do that (I'm passing a NSString).

Now, when the user clicks on a tableRow, I want to fire an other method and want to pass the same string.
I created a subclass of UITableViewCell and added the string to it.

**But** I can't get the value of the string in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.
That's because UITableView returns an UITableViewCell and not my custom subclass:

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].passString
    → /* Property 'passString not found on object of type UITableViewCell */
```

When I do `NSLog(@"%@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);` I can see the property on the log.

Now my question:
How can I get this subclass property in other methods?!

I don't want to subclass UITableView as well. I'd end up subclassing like *every* UIElement I'm using :'(

Thanks for help, greetings
Julian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jullian just type cast `UITableViewCell` to your custom class like

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell. passString; //it will work
```

or you can pass message instead of dot operator
`[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] passString];` 

it will give you warning but will work if it is the object of you CustomCell. Prefer using first method as I don't like warnings in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering!
I got it working.

For the first 30 minutest I just didn't know, what you'v meant and wrote Source for trash… :))

Comment: @jullian instead of answering your question you can comment on my answer... :D anyways it good that you got my point.